# Adjustment to Line of Apps Script Code

Tags: google-apps-script

Need  to adjust a line of code . Attached image of existing working code and Have highlighted in grey where I think amendment should go. Code will be like an "OR" function in Excel. Thanks.[Screen shot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saFvs.png)

```
function resetAll(e){
    var optionAB = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
            .requireValueInList(['Pin', 'Tie Clip'], true).build();
    var optionsABC = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
            .requireValueInList(['Pin', 'Tie Clip', 'Magnet'], true).build();
    var ss = e.source || SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var dataRange = ss.getDataRange()
    var values = dataRange.getValues();
    Logger.log('hello');
    for (var i = 19 ; i < values.length ; i++){
        var affectedCell = dataRange.offset(i,5,1,1);  // two steps to the right
        if(values[i][3] == '') {
            Logger.log(values[i])
            Logger.log(affectedCell.getValue())
            if (affectedCell.getValue() !== 'Pin')
                affectedCell.setValue('');    // reset if current choice is no longer legal
            affectedCell.setDataValidation(optionAB);
        }
        else {
            affectedCell.setDataValidation(optionsABC);      
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two negative comparisons using an `OR` won't work in the way you expect as what is positive for one will be negative for the other - so realistically you will always get a `True` response and the conditional block will execute.

If what you are checking is that neither `'Pin'` nor `'Tie Clip'` should be matched then it is an `AND` that you are looking for.

```
function resetAll(e) {
  var optionAB = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Pin', 'Tie Clip'], true).build(),
      optionsABC = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Pin', 'Tie Clip', 'Magnet'], true).build(),
      ss = (e.source || SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()),
      dataRange = ss.getDataRange(),
      values = dataRange.getValues(),
      affectedCell,
      i;

  for (i = 19 ; i < values.length ; i += 1){
    affectedCell = dataRange.offset(i,5,1,1);  // two steps to the right
    if(values[i][3] == '') {
      Logger.log(values[i])
      Logger.log(affectedCell.getValue())
      if (affectedCell.getValue() !== 'Pin' && affectedCell.getValue() !== 'Tie Clip') {
        affectedCell.setValue('');    // reset if current choice is no longer legal
        affectedCell.setDataValidation(optionAB);
      }
      else {
        affectedCell.setDataValidation(optionsABC);      
      }
    }
  }
}
```